# Shared transition element and Glide strategy

Tags: android, android-animation, image-loading, android-glide

I am trying to work on a shared element transition using Glide image loading library. I have a RecyclerView with hundreds of images so I would like to save the memory (if possible) and makes the animation working.

Glide creates a drawable that has the size of the target image so the shared element transition doesn't work well since the final image has different sizes (but the image has the same url).

How can I achieve shared element transition with Glide?
Is it possible to have memory saving and the animation at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done transitioning yet, but for the Glide part I would say use `.override()` on one or both loads. That'll force a cache hit. Of course passing/figuring out the correct size is up to you. Also you'll most likely need `.dontAnimate()` to prevent cross fade/fade in when transitioning.

Here're some other people trying to do the same:

- https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues?q=is%3Aissue+shared+element ([#285](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/285), [#502](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/502), [#627](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/627))
- [Android Glide library not working with shared element transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30923463/253468)
- [Ensuring That Images Loaded Only Come From Disk Cache](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/glidelibrary/TcFOy0tcxXA/discussion)