# Android shared element transition on ImageView scale is wrong

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

I have tried many different variations and cannot get the return transition to work properly.

When i exit Activity B the image transitions back to Activity A but it is scaled until it disappears then after disappearing is shows where it should.

I have tried different variations of the following and others in that group

Activity A
Coming from click listener in recyclerview.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ApplyActivity.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions;
            transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), imageView, getString(R.string.transition_image_details));
            intent.putExtra(ApplyActivity.EXTRA_NAME, selected_launcher);
            intent.putExtra(ApplyActivity.EXTRA_INSTALLED, mLaunchers.get(position).getInstalled());

            getActivity().startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

Activity A layout

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/launcher_icon"
android:transitionName="@string/transition_image_details"
android:layout_width="72dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Activity B

```
 Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);

        getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
        getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(transition);
```

I have tried the following true/false getWindow().setSharedElementsUseOverlay(true);

Activity B layout (within an AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout)

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/backdrop"
   android:transitionName="@string/transition_image_details"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="80dp"
   android:paddingTop="30dp"
   app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
   app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
```

change_image_transform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<changeTransform  />
<changeImageTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

I have tried setting the transition in values-v21/styles.xml too with no luck.

I have even tried setting the position from the recyclerview the transition name with no luck either.

Here is a video of the issue. I slowed down the transition so it could be seen better

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzli11ae3ebz95f/2016_04_19_20_33_29.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit, you have the problem in Activity A’s reenter transition. Take a look at this [link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) where you can find a good info about it.

Comment: Can I know why you have a mixed use of Transition API elements in XML and code?. I mean, you can achieve same behavior using just XML if you don't have to worry about APIS < 21. I can organice your question code if you want to achieve it :)

Comment: And last question: I guess you don't have to use `.setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition)`, it will take Enter and Exit Transitions if you don't define anything else. Can you try your code without that line of code pls?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the two images share the same `scaleType`.

Refer to this post for more info:
[Android Glide library not working with shared element transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923463/android-glide-library-not-working-with-shared-element-transitions)

Answer (score -2):

You can try removing these transiton codes in Activity B.I done that, and it worked well.