# Android shared element transition bug

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

As you can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/Tj95GsuHYHc), I am trying to animate the open of a new activity. The images are animated properly when opening the activity, but fail miserably when going back (I'm using `supportFinishAfterTransition()`)

I've tried all sorts of methods that I've found here or on Google, but nothing worked, i.e.:

Defining a transition under the res/transition:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

and then use it in both the styles of the main activity and the one that I'm opening:

```
<!-- enable window content transitions -->
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<!-- specify shared element transitions -->
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
```

I've also tried the same in my java code:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(...);
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(...);
```

From my view holder I'm starting the new activity by doing so:

```
private void openNewActivity() {
        String transitionName = "details";

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityCardDetails.class);

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(mImageView, transitionName);

        //noinspection unchecked
        ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((MainActivity)mContext,
                        mImageView,   // The view which starts the transition
                        transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
                );


        ActivityCompat.startActivity((MainActivity) mContext, intent, options.toBundle());
    }
```

This is the ImageView that starts the animation:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/business_card_image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

and this is the second ImageView that should animate it back:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/business_card_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/isFitSystemWindows"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_card_details"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

PS: I'm using Glide to load the images as this is user created content and I have no control over the aspect ratio of the images.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(toLoad)
     .fitCenter()
     .centerCrop()
     .crossFade()
     .into(mImageView);
```

I've been struggling with this issue for weeks now and I just can't seem to overcome it.

**Why can't it animate its bounds back?**

Thank you!

UPDATE: Apparently the bug is related to the image width. If I'm setting the width to a constant (say 200dp) the animation runs just fine in both ways, but if I'm setting the image width to `match_parent` the return animation is broken.

UPDATE2: I can pretty much say that this bug is related to the image loading lib (Glide or Picasso both have this issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the issue has been described before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923463/android-glide-library-not-working-with-shared-element-transitions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500754/android-shared-element-transition-bug). The issue comes indeed from the image loader.

The trick was to use `.dontTransform()` with

```
ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this)
ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(ActivityCardDetails.this)
```

to only play the animation when the image is properly loaded.

Comment: .dontTranforn() helped me