# Android fragment return transitions using shared elements with jetpack navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, shared-element-transition, android-jetpack-navigation

I've been migrating my application to the Android Jetpack navigation component, and am having difficulties with shared element transitions.

The `transitionName` attribute is set on both fragments, and I am starting the navigation using the following code (per [the animation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions)):

```
findNavController().navigate(
    MainFragmentDirections.actionViewEvent(event.name),
    FragmentNavigatorExtras(
        backgroundElement to "event_card",
        titleElement to "event_name"
    )
)
```

Initially, this alone didn't work at all. However, after adding the following code to the destination Fragment, the shared elements were animated on entry:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
}
```

However, **there is still no shared element *return* transition**. Is it possible to enable the transition on both enter and return? (I previously had this working when the two fragments were separate activities.)

It may be relevant to know I've overridden `onSupportNavigateUp` in the Activity as recommended by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) when using an action bar. The overridden method is below:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean =
        findNavController(R.id.nav_host).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
```

Comment: Where do you set the `sharedElementExitTransition`?

Comment: I had also set it in onCreate like the enter transition (in the destination fragment), but to no avail. I'll try setting it in the source fragment too. Although actually that was `sharedElementReturnTransition`, I couldn't find an exit property

Comment: Yep, still no return/exit transition with both properties set in the `onCreate` of both fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the failure to animate the return transition was because Glide was loading an image in the fragment to which I was returning.

I added a listener as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730583/2415238) and it fixed the problem.

I'll vote to close this question as a duplicate as while I didn't realise that was the issue at first, the solution is the same.